# Наклонение в придаточных уступки

Tags: синтаксис, наклонение

Можно ли утверждать, что сослагательное наклонение не используется в придаточных уступительных, а только в условно-уступительных конструкциях (где бы ни..., куда бы ни... и т.д.)?

Для сравнения:

Несмотря на то, что было холодно, снег на воротнике таял весьма скоро. (Валгина 2002, 325)

За что бы он ни брался, у него всё валилось из рук.

(хотя не знаю почему, действие в последнем примере кажется мне потенциально возможным в будущем, а не ирреальным)

Comment: Может быть во втором примере убрать "бы" и таким образом избавиться от сослагательного?  "За что он ни брался, у него всё валилось из рук."

Comment: Обратите внимание: в первом предложении нет сослагательного наклонения. В нем говорится о реально происходящим действии в прошлом.

Answer (score 2):

1) Несмотря на то, что было холодно, снег на воротнике таял весьма скоро.

Это **союзный подтип** уступительных предложений. Значение **реальной уступки** выражают союзы  НЕСМОТРЯ НА ТО ЧТО, ХОТЯ: "Котам обычно почему-то говорят "ты", хотя ни один кот никогда ни с кем не пил на брудершафт".

Значение **ирреальной уступки** выражает союз ХОТЯ  БЫ: Мы не можем браться за любую работу, хотя бы она и казалась привлекательной.

2) За что бы он ни брался, у него всё валилось с рук.

Это **относительный подтип** уступительных предложений (с относительными местоимениями и наречиями в роли союзных слов). В предложениях **с союзными словами КТО НИ, ЧТО НИ, ГДЕ НИ и др.** выражается **обобщенно-уступительное** значение и описываются **обобщенные или повторяющиеся ситуации**.

Хотя формально здесь может выражаться как реальное, так и ирреальное значение (разное наклонение глагола), противопоставление между ними **нейтрализуется** с помощью обобщенной семантики: **Что бы** **ни** предложили, он отказывается. **Что ни** предложат, он отказывается.

Comment: ... спасибо, Vera! я Вас правильно понимаю, в предложениях "За что бы он ни брался, у него всё валилось с рук." и "Что бы ни предложили, он отказывается." используется сослаг. наклон., так?.. 

в поисках примеров я столкнулась с этим заголовком http://www.chel.kp.ru/daily/26342.7/3224805/
разве "чтобы" в этом случае не надо писать раздельно?

Comment: Да, частица БЫ указывает на сослагательное наклонение. А в приведенном примере надо писать: Что бы там ни говорили ученые, а женщины сообразительнее мужчин.

Answer (score 1):

Сослагательное наклонение используется в формировании универсальных (генерализованных) условно-уступительных конструкциях как бы ни..., где бы ни..., куда бы ни..., какой бы ни..., что бы ни... и др.:

> Я инстинктивно чувствовала: пока меня волнует и этот ветер, и эти пламенные звезды, и стихи, ― до тех пор я жива, как бы ни тряслись ноги, как бы ни гнулся позвоночник под тяжестью носилок с раскаленными камнями. [Е. С. Гинзбург. Крутой маршрут (1990)]

Условно-уступительным конструкциям обязаны своим происхождением следующие уступительные выражения: неопределенные местоимения кто бы то ни было, что бы то ни было, какой бы то ни было и устойчивое выражение во что бы то ни стало.

См.: Русская корпусная грамматика